# Lightning Flow fails to trigger with Dataloader but works with manual update

Tags: lightning, visual-workflow

[image]

When I try to run the mass upload the record picklist And Text field value does not update but if I manually edit the record the flow triggers fine

1. Create a new Autolaunched flow
2. Double-click on the Start element in the canvas
3. Choose the trigger (the fast field update one), specify when the flow gets triggered (on create/update), and choose your object type (Interaction, for you)
4. Add a Decision element to the canvas that checks for the criteria you need ($Record.Interaction Status = Audit Require and $Record.Interaction Source = SIS) -- in the decision in the attached picture my object is Interaction.
5. Add an Assignment element to the canvas that assigns "New" to the field you need to change on $Record.

Comment: You can easily accomplish this field value assignment based on other fields’ value for any created/updated record of Interaction using Process Builder, no need to define a flow for that. Remember always going with the simplest automation tool for your use case.

Comment: once in production, I'm uploading over 90,000 records. Some of which have duplicate contacts with multiple opportunities. A process builder cannot handle this type of process